# Chaining mind controls

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

In a ZvZ, is it possible to mind control an enemy infestor, which then mind controls another infestor and so on? or are they immune to that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Controlled unit has all abilities to use. I've uploaded video demonstration to [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS_B2Y0y7EE)

Comment: Next step: Mind control a worker of another race and try to build a CC/Nexus. :)

Comment: @TomWij - I haven't played SC2 but didn't that work in SC1 if you were Protoss?

Comment: @Shinrai - I haven't played SC1 but Protoss can't do such thing anymore in SC2.

Comment: @Shinrai There is no dark archon in SC2. The mind control ability was given to the zerg in their infestor unit called neural parasite.

Comment: @TomWij there's actually an achievement for building a marine as zerg. ( I think. Might be a zealot)

Comment: @JKMach - Right, but my point was you could build the other races' tech trees. Tom's post read like he wasn't sure it was possible, but apparently I read it wrong. (I'm glad it's still available.)

Comment: My apologies, I tagged the wrong person. It was supposed to be @TomWij

Comment: @Raven-Dreamer Its for making a zealot. A marine is much harder as it requires multiple SCV mind controls to finish the CC, a nexus warps in fine.